# Extracting small area dataset from a large city data set by assigning coordinates as boundary

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I have a digital road map data of entire city in .csv format. I want to extract small region specific dataset from the main data set by self defined coordinates obtained from google earth. I want to define coordinates as boundary condition to extract the small area dataset.  I have converted the dataset to geodataframe but then how to proceed further. Thanks

Comment: You should provide an minimal example of what you have, and of what you would like to achieve

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

- you have not provided sample data.  Have used Ordinance Survey data of all roads in UK and *geojson* that is London, circular highway - M25
- have used https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.read_file.html **mask** to then restrict geometry to roads that intersect with M25 boundary
- in this case geometry is in multiple shape files, hence mask and `concat()` geometry in each file
- have demonstrated this works by plotting subset of more major roads inside M25

```
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely.geometry
import numpy as np
import requests, io
from pathlib import Path
from zipfile import ZipFile
import pandas as pd

# get uk road network
url = "https://api.os.uk/downloads/v1/products/OpenRoads/downloads?area=GB&format=ESRI®+Shapefile&redirect"
f = Path.cwd().joinpath("road_gp.zip")

if not f.exists():
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True, headers={"User-Agent": "XY"})
    with open(f, "wb") as fd:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=128):
            fd.write(chunk)
    zfile = ZipFile(f)
    zfile.extractall(f.stem)

# London circular motorway - M25    
gdf_london = gpd.read_file("https://skgrange.github.io/www/data/course_m25_boundary.json")
# load raods within M25
gdf = pd.concat(
    [
        gpd.read_file(sf, mask=gdf_london)
        .assign(source=sf.stem)
        for sf in list(Path.cwd().joinpath(f.stem).glob("**/*Link.shp"))
    ]
)

gdf
```

#### visualize

```
gdf.loc[~gdf["class"].isin(["Unclassified","Unknown","Not Classified",'Classified Unnumbered'])].explore()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. So I need to have a shape file of the area which I can mask upon the entire road map network. I will check that. I will also try to provide a sample dataset.

Comment: you need the geometry of area that you want to mask.  this could be a shape file, geojson, a shapely polygon any geometry that can be made a geodataframe